# К какому типу кодирования относится эта binary строчка(а именно рус буквы)

Tags: java, unicode, binary

При разборе binary файла столкнулся с тем, что в binary файле есть русские буквы и как их разобрать не знаю. в первых скобках написано в десятичном виде то что надо обработать а во второй то что должно получится. Я не понимаю к какой таблице кодирование это относится.

> (208 189 208 181 209 130)(нет)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это очень похоже на UTF-8.

Переводим два первых байта

```
208 189
```

в бинарный вид:

```
11010000 10111101
```

Выбираем только значащие биты:

```
   10000   111101
```

Переводим их в hex:

```
43D
```

Смотрим в таблице символов UTF-8 что за символ имеет код `U+043D`:

```
н
```

Символ сходится с первым символом в ожидаемой строке.

---

[Описание UTF-8 в Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).
[Таблица символов Unicode](https://unicode-table.com/ru/).

Comment: Всегда завидовал людям, которые так умеют манипулировать битами - респект :)